# EF core 6 result doesn't match the database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, ef-core-6.0

I execute a query and I don't always get the same result.

I executed the snippet below step by step with breakpoints.
The use case for this code is waiting until a certain process is no longer busy before continuing the execution.

- .NET 6.0
- EF Core 6.0.4

```cs
string slug = "abc";
Entity entity = await _resource.GetQueryable()
    .Where(x => x.Slug == slug)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
// entity.IsBusy is true

int retries = 0;
while(entity.IsBusy)
{
    if (retries > 10)
    {
        throw new SyncIsBusyException();
    }
    retries++;

    // Now I manually execute an SQL query on the database.
    // update Entities set IsBusy = 'false'

    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    entity = await _resource.GetQueryable()
        .Where(x => x.Slug == slug)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    // entity.IsBusy is still true (not in the DB)

    string test = await _resource.GetQueryable()
        .Where(x => x.Slug == slug)
        .Select(x => x.IsBusy)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    // test is false (which is correct)

    // test if creating a new variable changes things
    var test1 = await _resource.GetQueryable()
        .Where(x => x.Slug == slug)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    // test1.IsBusy is true (which is again incorrect)
}
```

The resource:

```cs
public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetQueryable()
{
    var queryable = _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();
    return queryable;
}
```

It looks like some kind of caching, but I don't have any set up. I can also see the SQL query being executed in the console. When I execute this generated SQL query manually on the DB I get the correct and expected result (IsBusy false).
I can fix this bug by adding a `bool isBusy = entity.IsBusy;` above the `while` and then using that. But I'd still like to know the underlying issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `Slug` the primary key of your entity?

The change tracker will cache the entity by its primary key, unless you clear the local cache (`dbContext.ChangeTracker.Clear()`) or query it with `.AsNoTracking()` in the first place.

The latter does prevent updates to the entity.

A `Select` query projects a subset of the entity, so that query *is* executed against the store.

Comment: The slug is not the primary key, but the AsNoTracking() fixes the issue when applied to the first query inside the `while`. I cannot use it because I do update it later.